# Handlebars to show one value or another depending on URL tag?

Tags: html, handlebars.js

In my code, I'm calling the data being passed below in Handlebars.js

```
  <section class="inner-wrapper">
    {{#each data.header }}
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    {{/each}}
  </section>
```

The value of title will either be "Results" or "Look" (stored in the json file) depending on the tag in the URL. If the URL is "websitename.com", it should show the "Results" title. If the URL is "websitename.com?tag=LO", it should show the "Look" title.

How do I write the handlebars template code to render one title or the other depending on the URLs above?

Comment: It sounds like it would be best to do the conditional logic in the JavaScript code and pass the result to the template method.

Comment: Could you provide some sort of example? How would the JS code look?